# how to prefetch directly unrelated fields in graphene django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I started using graphene and there are some thing I have not yet understood well for instance, when using nodes the I have this query

```
{
  orders {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fromUser {
          id
          username
          userprofile{
            image
            id
          }
        }
        toUser {
          id
          username
          userprofile{
            image
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it is very nice because it allows me to fetch profile and get image for a given profile that is related to a user even though user is foreign key in profile, however it is expensive in terms of queries that has to be done in order to get profile for every user

my models looks like this

```
class Order(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="from_user")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="to_user")
    ....

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

and my query as of now

```
orders = Order.objects.select_related('from_user','to_user').filter(
            Q(from_user=user) |
            Q(to_user=user)
            ).order_by("-id")
return orders
```

will appreciate if anyone could help me know how I can prefetch profile for both `from_user` and `to_user` in that case coz it really is expensive fetching the profile

Answer (score 0):

my bad should have tried what I was thinking first

```
orders = PaymentOrder.objects.select_related('from_user','to_user',"from_user__userprofile","to_user__userprofile").filter(
            Q(from_user=user) |
            Q(to_user=user)
            ).order_by("-id")
```

what solved